# Intellij, git, bitbucket whitespace problem

Tags: git, intellij-idea, format, bitbucket

I work in a team and we use Intellij to develop. Now share a code formatter so we have all the same formatted code. I have a strange behaviour (only I in the team): 
somethimes it happens taht when I push my changes on bitbucket it appears that I have changed all the file (if in bitbucket I set "ignore withespace" then I see only my really changes). So the problem is with withespaces.

I have checked with the other collegues that I have in git the

```
core.autocrlf=true
```

But the problem remains: randomly it happens that my file have a "withespace" problem. On java files and .properties files.....

Someone have some tips what I could check or compare with the coleagues? So that I don't have to pray everytime i commit/push?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is likely a result of EOL normalization in the committed files. IntelliJ calls git with `--ignored-errors` flag, which due to a bug in git versions between 2.16 and 2.21 actually result in normalization.

See for details https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205601

To solve the issue update git to 2.21 to solve this. Here is the commit fixing it in git https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e5da3d055c558fc6492d3b996736ff7e8d115c3

Comment: Hi I have updated git now... I will let you know if this fix it. For now thank you :)